# Redirect but keep an element

Tags: redirect, element

Is it possible using php,JS/Jquery to redirect an entire page but keep a single element on the page after the redirection?

Example:

```
<?php
header( "refresh:10;url=location2.php" );
?>

<div class="stay"> I want to stay!!</div>
```

Is there a way to have the div element stay once the redirection has completed or is this not possible?

Edit: I'm going to guess this is impossible without using an iframe and not actually redirecting the page itself.

Comment: You cannot.  When you redirect, it is a new page and you keep nothing from the page.  You may save text or binary *data* to persistent storage such as cookie or sessionStorage, but all *objects* in the old document will be destroyed when you leave it.  If you want to keey any object you need to stay on same page and use ajax and History API.

Comment: @Sheepy Thanks for clarifying that for me. I've begun creating an alternative means to achieve my goal now.